# cannot put <system.web.extensions> in webconfig file

Tags: web-config, asp.net-2.0

I am trying to add the following lines in the web config file. but it shows error on the first line. Can anyone suggest me where to exactly put this code on config file

```
<system.web.extensions>
<scripting>
  <webServices>
    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="5000"/>
  </webServices>
</scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

the error message is like the following

```
"the element 'configuration' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0' has invalid child element 'system.web.extensions' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0'. List of possible elements expected: 'system.net' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0'"
```

Comment: When you say you get error, what exactly do you mean? Please share the details here.

Comment: the element 'configuration' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0' has invalid child element 'system.web.extensions' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0'. List of possible elements expected: 'system.net' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0'

Comment: `system.we.extensions` - could it just be a typo since you have 'we' instead of 'web'?

Comment: no thats my careless mistake here...